# How can I get the conversations in instagram request folder with graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I have been struggle trying to get instagram requests folder conversations with Graph API.

I tried the endpoint

```
/{page-id}/conversations?platform=instagram&folder=requests
```

But it just returns all the instagram conversations.

Here is the link of the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations/